# Rotating sprite to original sprite location

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, sprite

Okay let me try to explain this..
So i have a player, that can lift different objects above his head.
Now he lifts the objects as they are in front of him, tilted - upside down - etc
I need the objects to return to their original position when lifted.
Is there a way to do this via anchor point?
I know that default anchor point is `ccp(0.5f, 0.5f)` which is the center, if i were to set the anchor point to the bottom left corner, how would i return the rotation to this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rotations are done relatieve to the anchor point of the node (sprite in your case). The default value of rotation is 0. No matter, what value of anchor point node uses, zero value of rotation property will return it to the initial state(I mean the state before begin any rotations).

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what i was looking for!
`sprite.rotation = 0`